# Coroutines Child Job Cancellation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

According to Job documentation, **the invocation of [cancel][Job.cancel] with exception (other than [CancellationException]) on this job also cancels parent**. Job.cancel function only accepts CancellationException. I am testing this behavior but cancelling a child job is not cancelling the parent job despite I am not using SupervisorJob.

```
/**
 * Creates a job object in an active state.
 * A failure of any child of this job immediately causes this job to fail, too, and cancels the rest of its children.
 *
 * To handle children failure independently of each other use [SupervisorJob].
 *
 * If [parent] job is specified, then this job becomes a child job of its parent and
 * is cancelled when its parent fails or is cancelled. All this job's children are cancelled in this case, too.

 * --The invocation of [cancel][Job.cancel] with exception (other than [CancellationException]) on this job also cancels parent.--
 *
 * Conceptually, the resulting job works in the same way as the job created by the `launch { body }` invocation
 * (see [launch]), but without any code in the body. It is active until cancelled or completed. Invocation of
 * [CompletableJob.complete] or [CompletableJob.completeExceptionally] corresponds to the successful or
 * failed completion of the body of the coroutine.
 *
 * @param parent an optional parent job.
 */

@Suppress("FunctionName")
public fun Job(parent: Job? = null): CompletableJob = JobImpl(parent)
```

So my test code is like;

```
fun main()  {
    val parentJob = Job()
    val scope = CoroutineScope(parentJob)

    suspend fun printText(text: String) {
        println("Before Delay: $text")
        delay(1000)
        println("After Delay: $text")
    }

    val job1 = scope.launch {
        printText("Job#1")
    }

    job1.invokeOnCompletion {
        println("Job#1 completed. Cause = $it")
    }

    val job2 = scope.launch {
        printText("Job#2")
    }

    job2.invokeOnCompletion {
        println("Job#2 completed. Cause = $it")
    }

    println(parentJob.children.joinToString { it.toString() } )

    job1.cancel(CancellationException())

    Thread.sleep(10000)

}
```

And the outputs like;

```
Before Delay: Job#1
Before Delay: Job#2
StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@462d5aee, StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@69b0fd6f
Job#1 completed. Cause = java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
After Delay: Job#2
Job#2 completed. Cause = null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My question is why the job#2 is not being cancelled?

**EDIT:**

After the answers from @broot and @Steyrix. I extended the test case.
Now printText(string) function throws exception if the given argument is "Job#1". So I am trying to simulate a viewmodel in android. Lets say that we created CoroutineScope(Job()) and I make two different requests. One of them is throwing exception but it is being caught by try-catch block. So other job continues doing its job and is not being cancelled.

So now the question is then what is the difference between SupervisorJob and Job. Why viewmodelscope (CloseableCoroutineScope(`SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate)`) uses SupervisorJob ?

Extended example;

```
fun main() {
    val parentJob = Job()
    val scope = CoroutineScope(parentJob)

    suspend fun printText(text: String) {
        println("Before Delay: $text")
        if (text == "Job#1") {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Test")
        }
        delay(1000)
        println("After Delay: $text")
    }

    val job1 = scope.launch {
        try {
            printText("Job#1")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e)
        }


    }

    job1.invokeOnCompletion {
        println("Job#1 completed. Cause = $it")
    }


    val job2 = scope.launch {
        printText("Job#2")
    }

    job2.invokeOnCompletion {
        println("Job#2 completed. Cause = $it")
    }

    println(parentJob.children.joinToString { it.toString() })


    Thread.sleep(10000)

}
```

Output;

```
Before Delay: Job#1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test
Job#1 completed. Cause = null
Before Delay: Job#2
StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@462d5aee
After Delay: Job#2
Job#2 completed. Cause = null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I don't really understand your extended example. You caught the exception, so this is like it never happened. If you don't catch it, then the problem will propagate and job2 will be cancelled. Cancellations propagate only to children, failures propagate to both children and parents. That makes a lot of sense for typical use cases of concurrent code.

Comment: If I do not catch it it will crash the application. My question is why we need that SupervisorJob. What is the exact difference between Job and SupervisorJob, If you can show me difference with a small usecase I will accept the answer and end the discussion.

Comment: Simply remove `try ... catch` in your example and you will see the difference. If using `Job()` the failure propagates, crashes the whole `scope` and `job2` is cancelled. If using `SupervisorJob()` the exception is simply ignored and other jobs progress as normal.

Comment: If this is not purely for learning purposes, then please share your specific use case. It sounds a little like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I have tried it already. If I use Job() and remove try catch, then if a crash happens in one of the child jobs then parent job will be cancelled. Thats right, but also application will crash that we do not want.  If I use SupervisorJob() then parent job will not be cancelled because of a crash occurred in a child job; but application will still be crashing. For example; the difference between supervisorScope and coroutineScope are clear and easy to understand. I will open an issue.

Comment: I don't explain this from the perspective of Android, but purely Kotlin/coroutines. `SupervisorJob` prevents propagating and it is fully analogous to `supervisorScope()`. If you say `viewModelScope` uses supervisor job underneath and children still crash the view/application, then I suspect they must have intentionally added some code to achieve such behavior. I don't know the context.

Comment: They will fix the docs. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/3589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it behaves according to the documentation you cited. You used a `CancellationException`, so it didn't cancel the parent.

The only confusing part in the documentation is why it mentions cancelling using other exception type than `CancellationException`. This is not possible. `cancel()` is for normal cancellations, not for failures, so it can never propagate to parents.

It looks like a small mistake in the documentation for a `Job()` function.

Comment: So how can I force second child to be cancelled when the first job is cancelled ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/):

> Normal cancellation of a job is distinguished from its failure by the
> type of this exception that caused its cancellation. A coroutine that
> threw CancellationException is considered to be cancelled normally. If
> a cancellation cause is a different exception type, then the job is
> considered to have failed. When a job has failed, then its parent gets
> cancelled with the exception of the same type, thus ensuring
> transparency in delegating parts of the job to its children.
>
> Note, that cancel function on a job only accepts CancellationException
> as a cancellation cause, thus calling cancel always results in a
> normal cancellation of a job, which does not lead to cancellation of
> its parent. This way, a parent can cancel its own children (cancelling
> all their children recursively, too) without cancelling itself.

```
job1.cancel(CancellationException())
```

Here you cancel the child job with `CancellationException`, therefore it is being cancelled "normally" and does not lead to parent cancellation and other children cancellation likewise.

Comment: I got this point but what I do not understand how can I achieve this cancellation behavior (cancel other children) ?

Comment: You can explicitly cancel parent job or throw an exception in the code of a child. However second approach is not what you want to do

Comment: Usually, you don't want all the children to be cancelled by one of them. You use explicit cancellation of the parent for it